# Quickbooks 2011 now requires UAC logn, but the currently logged on user and password WORKS FINE?

Tags: windows-7, uac, quickbooks

I have a real strange one... I do IT work for an accounting firm, and because they have such a diverse group of clients, they have many different versions of Quickbooks installed at once.  All employees run as "standard Users" (ie, not admin or power users).  All PC's are Win7-64 bit, fully patched via a local WSUS server.

Somehow about three weeks ago (maybe a month... perhaps last month's patch tuesday  caused it?) all of the users started reporting that the Quickbooks 2011 desktop icon was displaying with a "UAC Shield" on it and they were being prompted for a username and password when they invoked the program.

The strange thing is, the username and password that they were ALREADY LOGGED ON WITH worked to bypass this UAC prompt.  But once the program opened no network drives were available, almost as if they had been logged in with a separate copy of their profile but without the logon script running first so no mapped drives are available.

A complete reset of a given user's profile fixes the problem, but that is not a real acceptable solution...

So, any suggestions for ways that I can change the UAC prompting for this application?  There has to be something in the profile that causes this to happen that I can look into.

I appreciate any suggestions,

Glenn

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure why it suddenly wants "admin" rights to run Quckbooks... check the shortcut's properties & make sure the box doesn't have a tick in the "Advanced" -> "Run as Administrator" box.  If it is ticked... un-tick it.

When an application launches with UAC, the process is started in a separate environment from the running user minus any start-up scripts that would normally run.  If you switch to using UNC paths instead of local drive letters, I bet you won't have the problem.  (UAC will still pop up for whatever reason... but the files will still be accessible between the user sessions)

Comment: I have checked that... strangely enough, the "Run as Admin" is off, but it is set to run in XPSP3 Compatibility mode.  Shutting that off makes the application no longer start.  But if I delete the user's profile and let Windows create a new one it works fine (with compatibility mode off).  But the problem happened on all Windows 7 machines at about the same time, all across the network.  That's why I suspect maybe it was a patch.